# JSON Multidimension printing

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, json

I have to print json in following format

```
> { header: [ { "signinpage": "ABC" }, { "signinpage": "XYZ" }, {
> "signinpage": "PQR" }, { "signinpage": "ERT" } ] }
```

i have used the following code :

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
  {
    $rows[] = $row["customer"];
  }

  if(mysql_num_rows($res)!= 0)
     {  
      if (!isset($responses[$row['$header']= array ()]))
      {
        for ($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++)
        {
           if(isset($responses[$row['$header']])) 
           {
              $responses[$row[$header]] = array('signinpage'=>$rows[$i]); 
           }  
         }
       }
       header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
       header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
       header('Content-type: application/json; charset="utf-8"');
       echo json_encode($responses);
     }
```

I am new to JSON and finding it difficult to print can anyone help me to get the desired output.Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is is your current output?

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: responses in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\sign2.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br />
null

Comment: Why did you put $ symbol before your array index?(like $row['$header'] etc..)

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\sign2.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\sign2.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\sign2.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\sign2.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
<br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with your loop. I can't see where your $row / $header variables are set and what is in there. And the isset condition you wrote is wrong. Try something like this:

```
$responses = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC))  {
    $rows[] = $row["customer"];
}

if(mysql_num_rows($res)!= 0) {  
    if (!isset($responses[$row['$header']])) {
        // in case it is not set, create an array..,
        $responses[$row['$header']]= array();
        for ($i=0; $i<count($rows); $i++) {
            // for each row add your assoziative array to it
            $responses[$row[$header]][] = array('signinpage'=>$rows[$i]); 
        }
    }
}
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json; charset="utf-8"');
echo json_encode($responses);
```

Comment: {
"": [ //i want to print a header name
{
"signinpage": "ABC"
},
{
"signinpage": "XYZ"
},
{
"signinpage": "PQR"
},
{
"signinpage": "ERT"
}
]
}

Answer (score 0):

`$responses = array();` add this linw just before your while loop.

```
$responses = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
  {
    $rows[] = $row["customer"];
  }

  if(mysql_num_rows($res)!= 0)
     {  
      if (!isset($responses[$row['$header']= array ()]))
      {
        for ($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++)
        {
           if(isset($responses[$row['$header']])) 
           {
              $responses[$row[$header]] = array('signinpage'=>$rows[$i]); 
           }  
         }
       }
       header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
       header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
       header('Content-type: application/json; charset="utf-8"');
       echo json_encode($responses);
     }
```

What is $header in your code it is not assigned with any value.

`if (!isset($responses[$row['$header']= array ()]))` this is wrong. key can not be array

Answer (score 0):

Try this now it should work for you:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { 
$rows[$row['$header']][]['signinpage']=$row['customer'];
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

May this will help you!

Comment: Array will not work like this `$rows['header'][]['signinpage']` you can not give `[]` in middle

Comment: I think [] in middle it will work like auto increment index for array.

Comment: {"header":[{"signinpage":"ABC"},{"signinpage":"XYZ"},{"signinpage":"PQR"},{"signinpage":"ERT"}]}<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: responses in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\sign2.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />
null